# How to assign variable to python using GDB's new python support?

Tags: python, gdb

Recently I came across with surprise the the current version of GDB support python scrippting, which very likely means I can plot variables while debugging the program -- something I dreamed about a long time ago. However, I quickly get stuck because I can't get a variable's value "out of" GDB and assign it to a python variable. The method should be inside the gdb module, but I don't know which function to call. Anybody knows? Tell me please :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

To access the variable `x` in the currently selected gdb frame, you can use

```
x = gdb.selected_frame().read_var("x")
```

This will assign a [`gdb.Value`](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Values-From-Inferior.html) instance to `x`.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very helpful, and the link is informative. Just another question: I have a Fortran array assigned to a python variable "x" in this way, and I'd like to convert this gdb.Value type to a python list -- I have to do this element by element, right ? Because there doesn't seem to be a single function to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: @mayasky: It should be possible to directly convert the address to some `ctypes` or NumPy array, but I don't know exactly how.